# Setting up pyspark on windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, pyspark, anaconda

I tried to install spark on my windows 10 machine. I have anacondo2 with python 2.7. I managed to open the ipython notebook instance. I am able to run the following lines:

```
airlines=sc.textFile("airlines.csv")
print (airlines)
```

But I get an error when I run:  `airlines.first()`

Here's the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-85a5d6f5110f> in <module>()
----> 1 airlines.first()

C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in first(self)
   1326         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1327         """
-> 1328         rs = self.take(1)
   1329         if rs:
   1330             return rs[0]

C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1308 
   1309             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1310             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1311 
   1312             items += res

C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    932         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
    933         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
--> 934         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    935 
    936     def show_profiles(self):

C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
    137         break
    138     if not sock:
--> 139         raise Exception("could not open socket")
    140     try:
    141         rf = sock.makefile("rb", 65536)

Exception: could not open socket
```

I get a different error when I execute: `airlines.collect()`

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3745b2fa985a> in <module>()
      1 # Using the collect operation, you can view the full dataset
----> 2 airlines.collect()

C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    775         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
    776             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
--> 777         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    778 
    779     def reduce(self, f):

C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
    140     try:
    141         rf = sock.makefile("rb", 65536)
--> 142         for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):
    143             yield item
    144     finally:

C:\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py in load_stream(self, stream)
    515         try:
    516             while True:
--> 517                 yield self.loads(stream)
    518         except struct.error:
    519             return

C:\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py in loads(self, stream)
    504 
    505     def loads(self, stream):
--> 506         length = read_int(stream)
    507         if length == SpecialLengths.END_OF_DATA_SECTION:
    508             raise EOFError

C:\spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py in read_int(stream)
    541 
    542 def read_int(stream):
--> 543     length = stream.read(4)
    544     if not length:
    545         raise EOFError

C:\Users\AS\Anaconda2\lib\socket.pyc in read(self, size)
    382                 # fragmentation issues on many platforms.
    383                 try:
--> 384                     data = self._sock.recv(left)
    385                 except error, e:
    386                     if e.args[0] == EINTR:

error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL PYSPARK on Windows 10 
JUPYTER-NOTEBOOK With ANACONDA NAVIGATOR

### STEP 1

**Download Packages**

1) spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz [Download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

2) java jdk 8 version [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

3) Anaconda v 5.2 [Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

4) scala-2.12.6.msi [Download](http://scala-2.12.6.msi)

5) hadoop v2.7.1[Download](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)

### STEP 2

MAKE SPARK FOLDER IN **C:/** DRIVE AND PUT EVERYTHING INSIDE IT 
[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTrv.png)

**NOTE : DURING INSTALLATION OF SCALA GIVE PATH OF SCALA  INSIDE SPARK FOLDER**

### STEP 3

NOW SET NEW WINDOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

1. `HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\hadoop`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`
3. `SCALA_HOME=C:\spark\scala\bin`
4. `SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark\bin`
5. `PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe`
6. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe`
7. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook`
8. **NOW SELECT PATH OF SPARK** : EDIT AND ADD NEW

   Add "**C:\spark\spark\bin**” to variable “Path” Windows

### STEP 4

- Make folder where you want to store Jupyter-Notebook outputs and files
- After that open Anaconda command prompt and **cd Folder name**
- then enter **Pyspark**

thats it your browser will pop up with Juypter localhost

### STEP 5

Check pyspark is working or not !

Type simple code and run it

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
a = Row(name = 'Vinay' , age=22 , height=165)
print("a: ",a)
```